# What does 「雷鍋氣心樓，猴氣猴嗨賽雷敢窩」 mean?

Tags: cantonese, slang

[image]

The above is a screenshot from a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHCV9WdayTM&list=PLoY-UzHQ78ZINXb7gy5OM_HpQ8SIHrGBF)

I am a native Cantonese speaker, even I can't figure out what 「雷鍋氣心樓，猴氣猴嗨賽雷敢窩」」 meant. I am sure it is not 「這件事就當沒發生過」

I have no problem with the rest. E.g. 破該，催咩 = 仆街，吹咩, so no need to explain them.

*My thinking is, since someone posted, someone must know what it means*

Answer (score 2):

At first, I thought it is a long sentence, may not be a common searchable phrase, but I took a shot and search 雷鍋氣心樓，猴氣猴嗨賽雷敢窩 anyway. To my surprise, I found the following

> [雷锅气心楼，猴气猴嗨赛雷敢窝.什么意思](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/2076960235275419788.html)

> **给个面子我，这件事当没发生过**。
> 粤语，广东地区称为广东话、广府话，广西地区称为白话，是一种声调语言，属汉藏语系汉语>>族汉语方言。是广东地区广府民系和广西地区白话人的母语。在中国南方的广东中西部、广>西东南部及香港、澳门和东南亚的部分国家或地区，以及海外华人社区中广泛使用。

So, it does mean "这件事当没发生过"?

No!

on the same page CAOHANJVA wrote:

> 雷锅气心楼，猴气猴嗨赛雷敢窝

> **你个咸湿老，好似好西犀利咁喔**

It means: "you pervert! Like you are damn amazing, or something

**Edit:**

monalisa wrote in comment:

> 气心 sounds more like 黐綫. Crazy guy, not pervert

> I think this is using Mandarin pronunciation to approximate Cantonese sounds. When you read 气心 in Mandarin, it sounds like 黐綫 in Cantonese

The real answer could be **你個黐綫佬，好似好西犀利咁喎**

Comment: 气心 sounds more like 黐綫. Crazy guy, not pervert.

Comment: 气心 sounds like 黐綫 in Mandarin maybe, but it doesn't in Cantonese. I am not sure the sentence is pronounced in Cantonese or Mandarin.

Comment: I think this is using Mandarin pronunciation to approximate Cantonese sounds. When you read 气心 in Mandarin, it sounds like 黐綫 in Cantonese. Same with the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @monalisa No wonder I couldn't make sense of it. The other examples are close enough between Cantonese and Mandarin. Does 咸湿 sound like 气心 at all?

Comment: No, they do not sound like each other remotely. And while I am at this, the explanation in parentheses are not the equivalent of what precedes either. This whole thing seems like a childish way of getting people to use foul language unknowingly. I suggest closing this question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a commenet above by monalisa, this image is trying to trick mandarin speaker to use foul language or bad words unknowingly. So let me put what the sentences actually mean in Cantonese here.

破該，催咩：仆街，吹咩？

仆街 was originally 仆街死，cursing people die on the street. 吹咩 is like 'so what?' or 'what are you going to do?'. Not bad words, but provocative.

丟雷樓某：屌你老母

Means f___ your mother.

雷鍋氣心樓，猴氣猴嗨賽雷敢窩：你個黐綫佬，好似好閪犀利咁喎

Explained in detail in Tang Ho's answer, it means 'you pervert! Seems like you are damn amazing.'

肉鵝啊鎖嗨：郁我啊傻閪

Fight me, stupid ____

達鵝啊本：打我啊笨

Fight me, stupid. (No bad words, but again, provocative)

餓系雷摟逗：我係你老豆

I am your father. (No bad words, not even provocative. Cantonese speaking people will just think that you are stupid if you say this to them.)